# Question about partially ordered sets and how to order them?

Tags: order-theory

If I had a partially ordered set (E, ≤) where E = {1,2,3}, how would I order it? In other words, if I wanted to show the set, would I need to conform to the definition of ≤? So would it be {(1,2), (1,3), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)} since 1 ≤ 2 and 3 and 1 ≤ 1, 2 ≤ 2, and 3 ≤ 3. Would this also mean that (3,1) would not appear since 3 is not less than 1? Or does the definition not matter?

Comment: $\leq$ must be reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive. You can define the order of your elements however you like, as long as the conditions for $\leq$ are satisfied.

Comment: So I would need to create the set around the definition of ≤, not just throw ordered pairs in?

Comment: Let's assume you have a set $E :=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and a relation $R$ which we will call $\leq$. Since your objective is to construct a partially ordered set, there must be, at the least, an ordering relation defined on the set $E$. How elements $x,y\in E$ are in relation with one another is up to you decide, but $\leq$, must satisfy the three conditions mentioned earlier